# Log-like operator with math inside (e.g. p-lim)

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators

I am looking to make a log-like operator that looks the same as `$p \text{-lim}$`.

The best way so far I found to do this is

- `\DeclareMathOperator*{\plim}{\text{$p$-lim}}`

> **Question: Is this the best way to do this?**
>
> It seems like a bit of a hack.  If I remove `\text{...}` then it doesn't work.

(Also, I know I can use `\operatorname*` to give a more flexible implementation like

- `\newcommand{\plog}[1]{\operatorname*{\text{$#1$-lim}}`

where now I can change the p to, say, a p+q when needed.)

Comment: You could just do `\DeclareMathOperator*{\plim}{-lim}` and use it in math mode as `p\plim` and `(p+q)\plim`. (Not very logic markup like …)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, this will put too much of a space between "p" and "-lim".  The is also the trouble with $p\text{-}\lim$, except now the space is on the other side.  Another issue with both is that in display mode the subscript is centered below -lim (or lim) and not under p-lim.

Comment: Borrow from egreg's answer `\DeclareMathOperator*{\plim}{\mkern-1mu-lim}` and adjust. I didn't thought about a subscript, though. For that you still need the full operator without the need to manually align the subscript.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The argument to `\DeclareMathOperator` is processed in math mode, but with special settings to make hyphens not come out as minus signs. However letters will appear in roman upright type. But we have all the math mode tools available:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\plim}{\mathnormal{p}\mkern2mu-lim}
```

(the `\mkern2mu` is because the *p* would be too near to the hyphen.

The "variable argument" version could be

```
\newcommand{\plim}[1]{\operatorname*{\mathnormal{#1}\mkern2mu-lim}}
```

If you need also a real minus sign in the argument, then you have to restore its mathcode:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\edef\minusmathcode{\the\mathcode`- }}
\newcommand{\restoreminusinop}{\mathcode`-=\minusmathcode\relax}
\newcommand{\plim}[1]{%
  \operatorname*{\mathnormal{\restoreminusinop#1}\mkern2mu-lim}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about mathnormal.  Also your spacing looks best.  I also realize from your explanation that one needs to be careful if a minus sign is in the argument.  It will show as a dash.  (Luckily, my application doesn't use "p-q" as an argument to the limit.)

Comment: @JasonRute I've added a trick for getting a real minus sign in the argument.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same as in egreg's answer, without `amsmath` nor `AtBeginDocument` trick:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\plim{\mathop{p\mkern2mu\mathrm{\mathchar"702D lim}}}

\begin{document}
$\plim_{a\to\infty}$

$\displaystyle\plim_{a\to\infty}$
\end{document}
```

Sometimes the math alphabet command `\mathrm` does not use the same font as would be used in operator names. So the following slightly more complicated solution does it:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\plim{\mathop{p\mkern2mu{\operator@font\mathchar"702D lim}}}
\makeatother
```

And regarding the hardcoding of the text hyphen slot, ... well one can complicate the code if one wishes to go around this problem.  By the way I am not sure I correctly understood the OP, as here I tried my best to use the hyphen slot (ascii code 45) from <strike>the</strike> a <strike>text</strike> font (shorter usually than a minus sign), and not a `\textendash` which looks more like a minus sign.

(Sorry I got slightly confused in my explanations, as the math symbol font `operators` (used - if it has not been modified - by `\operator@font`) is not necessarily 'the' document 'text' font, not is it necessarily the font used by `\mathrm` (although it is in the default set-up) but it is at any rate 'a' font, hence my striking out edit in the paragraph above.)

Comment: The purpose of `\minusmathcode` is avoiding to hardwire a number which might not be correct: family 0 *usually* refers to the text font, but it is not always true.

Comment: In the initial font set-up in math mode for TeX/LaTeX, there are 4 fonts: the `operators` (digits, uppercase Greek, the plus sign, ...,  used for log-like names), the `letters` (Latin letters, lowercase Greek),  the `symbols` (includes the calligraphic alphabet), and the `large symbols` (`\sum`, delimiters). And the minus sign `$-$` is slot 0 is the `symbols` font. Slot 45 of the `operators font` gives a hyphen-like character, shorter. Slot 43 of the `operators font` is the plus sign $+$. Notice the awkwardness of this: slot 43 of one font must match in length slot 0 of another font!