# How to write a modified limit operator?

Tags: math-operators

I am trying to write an generalised limit operator, which look approximately like the standard \lim, except it has an additional symbol in front, connected by a hyphen (see example below). I would very much like this generalised limit to really look like the good old \lim; in particular, if I take limit over a variable x, then I would like the symbol x to be placed below. I almost managed to accomplish this by exploiting the old \lim, and adding the prefix:

```
> p \!\! - \!\! \lim_x
```

However, if I replace x by a longer string (say, several variables), I get too much whitespace. I tried grouping the limit into a single object, like below, but this leads to the variable being placed right of the limit symbol, not below:

```
> {p \!\! - \!\! \lim}_x
```

Could someone please advise me what is the best way of writing such a limit?

Here is a minimal example and the output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage
\begin{document}

Naive example: 
$$
p-\lim_{x} f(x), \qquad
p-\lim_{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n} f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)
$$

With \verb"\!" used for indentation, without grouping: 
$$
p\!\!-\!\!\lim_{x} f(x), \qquad
p\!\!-\!\!\lim_{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n} f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)
$$

With \verb"\!" used for indentation, plus grouping  : 
$$
{p\!\!-\!\!\lim}_{x} f(x), \qquad
\operatorname{p\!\!-\!\!\lim}\limits_{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n} f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)
$$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73232/log-like-operator-with-math-inside-e-g-p-lim?

Comment: @egreg: No, I did not, but that looks very relevent. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\plim}{p-lim}
```

in your preamble, which will define a command `\plim` which you can use in your document with, for example,

```
\plim_{x\to\infty} f(x)
```

This will produce a roman (upright) 'p'. If you want an italic 'p', the definition should be

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\plim}{\mathit{p}-lim}
```

Comment: The “p” will be upright, which probably isn't wanted.

Comment: This is precisely what I needed, thank you! I replaced \DeclareMathOperator* by a \newcommand with \operatorname* so that I could replace p by other, but other than that, you solution works perfectly.

Comment: The right command is `\mathnormal`, but this is already covered in the question I linked as duplicate.